# Battery status of an external device on HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, device, battery, batterylevel

I have a PIC18 that sends its Vcc level of battery charge on a mysql database. I was wondering if there is a script to display its battery-status on my website homepage. I mean something like a typical mobile battery icon to display over my website navbar.
Sorry but my javascript knowledge is so limited.
Thanks for answers.

Comment: What is external device?

Comment: I think you want battery status of user, so use https://tutorialzine.com/2016/08/working-with-the-javascript-battery-api

Answer (score 0):

To get battery status of user, use following javascript code to get battery status using javascript:

```
navigator.getBattery().then(function(batteryManager) { 
// Get current charge in percentages. var level =
batteryManager.level * 100; 
}).catch(function(e) { console.error(e); });
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
I mean that i have a value in a database that indicates the battery level of a remote device so i want to put it in a script and display a battery logo with the real charge